# Update page(s) to farm without touching codes that were previously deployed via wsp

Tags: development, solution-package

I'm facing a situation where I only wish to update one page of the farm solution and do not wish to touch the existing codes that were previously deployed onto the farm.

Why do I wish to do so is because there might be a code difference and I do not wish to risk it, thus I'm trying to see if I'm able to deploy only the selected files onto the farm without having to worry about code difference?

Am I able to do so with Sharepoint 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the wsp from the farm environment using PowerShell code

$farm = Get-SpFarm
$file = $farm.Solutions.Item(“sharepoint.wsp”).SolutionFile
$file.SaveAs(“C:\sharepoint.wsp”)

Changed the wsp to cab to access the dll file

Then I used dotPeek to open the dll files to compare the codes from the farm and the ones I have before I am sure to deploy it onto a test environment for testing.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would be able to do this. Farm solution has a dll associated which will be deployed to GAC during solution deployment. Now as soon as you build new WSP, this dll would be build using the current code in visual studio.

Now when you say pages(and there is no change in code behind), You can just re upload page manually. But if you have change in code behind. You might have to create new solution(not recommended though.